# Java Swing Table Header not displayed properly when column is resized

Tags: java, swing, header, resize, jtable

This is Java swing awt related question.
I am using, JXTable (an extension of JTable). The table has 3 fixed (always displayed) columns. Lets call them "OK-COLS" because they are displayed as required.
The header of OK-COLs have two components = JLabel (To indicate column name) and JButton (For sorting that column)
The table can have one or more than one "NOT-OK-COLS" at runtime.
The headers of NOT-OK-COLS, have 3 components: - JLabel (To indicate column name), a combo box (to filter the table), and a sort button.

**Problem**: -
If NOT-OK-COL is clicked for sorting, and then the column width is resized, the header of that col does not adjust to new column width immediately.
After resize of NOT-OK-COL, if other column's header are clicked, then the NOT-OK-COL's header resizes properly as per column width.

Need help to find why this problem is occuring and how it can be resolved.
The table uses its own, custom renderer.

Attaching some screenshots for reference: -

1) When Table is simply displayed, no resizing or sorting of columns done: -
[image: When Table is simply displayed, no resizing or sorting of columns]

2) When OK-COLs are resized 
[image: When OK-COLs are resized]

3) When NOT-OK-COL is resized (without sorting ... 1st column on left hand side width is increased)
[image: When NOT-OK-COL is resized]

4) When NOT-OK-COL is sorted and resized (1st column on LHS's width is reduced)
[image]

As can be seen in the last image, the "Value 2" column header is overlapped by the header of the 1st column, it did not re size to its actual new width.

Now if i click on any other header, the header of 1st column will resize automatically as desired (similar to image # 2)

Following are the classes of the example.

DemoClass.java (public static void main)

EditableHeaderRenderer.java

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
package com.tejpal.finalHeader.two;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

import java.awt.*;

public class DemoClass extends JFrame {

    /**
     * Main class that will fire up the UI on the screen
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public DemoClass() {
        super("Main Frame");

        JPanel cPane = (JPanel) getContentPane();
        cPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // List of values for the combo box
        String[] list = {"tejpal","singh","chouhanfromkhnadwa"};


        DefaultTableColumnModel tableModel = new DefaultTableColumnModel();


        TableColumn col = null; 

        JPanel firstpanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        /**
         * This subpanel holds the three components.
         * Label, combobox, Sort Button
         */ 
        JPanel subPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        //Add Label to the header panel
            subPanel.add( new JLabel("Label"), BorderLayout.WEST);

            //Add combo box to the header panel
            subPanel.add( new JComboBox<String>(list));

            // Add sort button to the header panel
            JButton sortWidget = new JButton();



            sortWidget.setOpaque(false);
            sortWidget.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            sortWidget.setBorderPainted(false);
            sortWidget.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            sortWidget.setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("Table.ascendingSortIcon") );
            subPanel.add( sortWidget,BorderLayout.EAST);
            //adding subpanel to firstPanel 
            firstpanel.add(subPanel);
            firstpanel.setSize(10, 100);
            firstpanel.setVisible(true);




          col = new TableColumn(0);
          col.setPreferredWidth( 100 );
          col.setMinWidth( 100 );   

          //EditableHeaderRenderer implements TableCellRenderer and rendered column as header of table with panel 
          col.setHeaderRenderer(new EditableHeaderRenderer(firstpanel));
          tableModel.addColumn(col);




          JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
       // second panel with label and button
          JPanel subPanelSecond = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

            //Add Label to the header panel
          subPanelSecond.add( new JLabel("Label"));

            // Add sort button to the header panel
            JButton sortWidgetSecond = new JButton();
            sortWidgetSecond.setOpaque(false);
            sortWidgetSecond.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            sortWidgetSecond.setBorderPainted(false);
            sortWidgetSecond.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT); 
            subPanelSecond.add( sortWidgetSecond,BorderLayout.EAST);
            sortWidgetSecond.setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("Table.ascendingSortIcon") );
            // adding subPanelSecond on secondPanel
            secondPanel.add(subPanelSecond);
            secondPanel.setSize(10, 100);
            secondPanel.setVisible(true);

          col = new TableColumn(1);
          col.setPreferredWidth( 100 );
          col.setMinWidth( 100 );
        //EditableHeaderRenderer implements TableCellRenderer and rendered column as header of table with panel 
          col.setHeaderRenderer(new EditableHeaderRenderer(secondPanel));
          tableModel.addColumn(col);



          col = new TableColumn(2);
          col.setPreferredWidth( 100 );
          col.setMinWidth( 100 );
        //EditableHeaderRenderer implements TableCellRenderer and rendered column as header of table with panel 
          col.setHeaderRenderer(new EditableHeaderRenderer(secondPanel));
          tableModel.addColumn(col);



          col = new TableColumn(3);
          col.setPreferredWidth( 100 );
          col.setMinWidth( 100 );
        //EditableHeaderRenderer implements TableCellRenderer and rendered column as header of table with panel 
          col.setHeaderRenderer(new EditableHeaderRenderer(secondPanel));
          tableModel.addColumn(col);



        JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(), tableModel);


        // code for insert row data in table
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(); 
        for(int i=0;i<table.getColumnCount();i++){
            model.addColumn(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i));
        }

        Object[] rowDate0 = new Object[]{new Integer(21), "b", "c","d"};
        Object[] rowDate1 = new Object[]{new Integer(11), "11","chouhan","khandwa"};
        Object[] rowDate2 = new Object[]{new Integer(27),"11","abc", "test"};
        Object[] rowDate3 = new Object[]{new Integer(2),"a", "b", "3"};

        model.addRow(rowDate0);
        model.addRow(rowDate1);
        model.addRow(rowDate2);
        model.addRow(rowDate3);

        table.setModel(model);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        cPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);    
        setSize(800, 200);
        setResizable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        // main class
        new DemoClass();
    }
}
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
package com.tejpal.finalHeader.two;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;



/**
 * EditableHeaderRenderer implements TableCellRenderer and rendered column as header of table with panel 
 * 
 */

class EditableHeaderRenderer extends JPanel implements TableCellRenderer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static JTable table = null;
    private MouseEventReposter reporter = null;
    private JComponent editor;
    // passed jbomponent will be displayed on header of table
    EditableHeaderRenderer(JComponent editor) {
        this.editor = editor;
        this.editor.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
    }
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
        if (table != null && EditableHeaderRenderer.table != table) {
            table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(false);
            EditableHeaderRenderer.table = table;
            final JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();   
            if (header != null) {   
                header.setSize(new Dimension(150,80));
                System.out.println(header.getDefaultRenderer()+ " :::::::: ");
                this.editor.setForeground(header.getForeground());   
                this.editor.setBackground(header.getBackground());   
                this.editor.setFont(header.getFont());
                // calling mouse event.         
                reporter = new MouseEventReposter(header, col, this.editor);
                header.addMouseListener(reporter);
            }
        }
        return this.editor;
    }

    /**
     * EditableHeaderRenderer extends MouseAdapter to perform any mouse action like click,pressed,release ....etc 
     * 
     */
    static public class MouseEventReposter extends MouseAdapter {

        private Component dispatchComponent;
        private JTableHeader header;
        private int column  = -1;
        private Component editor;

        public MouseEventReposter(JTableHeader header, int column, Component editor) {
            this.header = header;
            this.column = column;
            this.editor = editor;
        }

        public MouseEventReposter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public void setColumn(int column) {
            this.column = column;
        }

        private void setDispatchComponent(MouseEvent e) {
            int col = header.getTable().columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
            if (col != column || col == -1) return;

            Point p = e.getPoint();
            Point p2 = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(header, p, editor);
            dispatchComponent = SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(editor, p2.x, p2.y);
        }

        private boolean repostEvent(MouseEvent e) {
            if (dispatchComponent == null) {
                return false;
            }
            MouseEvent e2 = SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(header, e, dispatchComponent);
            dispatchComponent.dispatchEvent(e2);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            dispatchComponent = null;
            header.remove(editor);
            repostEvent(e);

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {

            String[] list = {"tejpal","singh","chouhan"};

             int col1 = table.columnAtPoint(event.getPoint());
                String name = table.getColumnName(col1);
                System.out.println("Column index selected " + col1 + " " + name);
                // on mouse click changing the image of button for sorting.selecting column index and changing sort image of particular column. 
            if(col1==0){
                  if (header.getResizingColumn() == null) {
                        Point p = event.getPoint();

                        int col = header.getTable().columnAtPoint(p);
                        if (col != column || col == -1) return;

                        int index = header.getColumnModel().getColumnIndexAtX(p.x);
                        if (index == -1) return;

                        editor.setBounds(header.getHeaderRect(index));
                        header.add(editor);
                        editor.validate();
                        setDispatchComponent(event);
                        repostEvent(event);
                    }
                TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
                //JPanelMainClass m = new JPanelMainClass(list, 1+"");
                //EditableHeaderRenderer implements TableCellRenderer and rendered column as header of table with panel 
                JPanel firstpane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                 JPanel subPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                    //Add Label to the header panel
                    JLabel label  = new JLabel("Label");
                    subPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);

                    //Add combo box to the header panel
                    subPanel.add( new JComboBox<String>(list));

                    // Add sort button to the header panel
                    final JButton sortWidget = new JButton();



                    sortWidget.setOpaque(false);
                    sortWidget.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                    sortWidget.setBorderPainted(false);
                    sortWidget.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
                    sortWidget.setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("Table.ascendingSortIcon") );
                    subPanel.add( sortWidget,BorderLayout.EAST);
                    //adding a label,combobox and button on panel and button has image icon. that can be ascending or descending 
                    firstpane.add(subPanel);
                    firstpane.setSize(10, 100);
                    firstpane.setVisible(true);

                column.setHeaderRenderer(new EditableHeaderRenderer(firstpane));
                // table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
            }
        }}

}
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for JTable / XxxTableModel in local variable

Comment: i have the code but those are several files, is their any option in SO, using which i can upload entire project (zip, rar) and users can import and test it out directly instead of lengthy post full of codes ? .. .also are you guys able to see the screenshots ? :( i have tried to upload them but not visible to me

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: edited question so that screenshots are visible, will upload the MCVE soon...

Comment: Apologies for the delay, posting the code now...

Comment: Looks like a code dump. Please re-read the links and create a minimal example.

Comment: i have tried to compress the code as much as possible with just two java classes, and they have hard coded values for sample table rows, so i believe, the MCVE criteria is fulfilled here now. Updating the post with new code, kindly have a look and please help.

Comment: Please read [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) in the tutorials.

Comment: @user1803551 the link you have provided talks about how to sort or filter, but here the problem is more of related to how the headers are displayed and get distorted... any idea what might be happening, that the header does not get re sized as expected ?

Comment: I think you didn't implement the sorting and filtering properly - you did custom changes that Swing would have done for you and that has to do with your problem. Try to start from the working tutorial's code and modify it to see if you still get the problem.